# Basic containment of matrix groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be the following group where A and B are subgroups of G.

$G= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \ : \  a \in \mathbb{R} / \{0\},\  b \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace$

$A= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \  : \ a \in \mathbb{R} / \{0\} \right\rbrace$

$B= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \ : \  b \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace$

I)Prove that $BA=G $

Proof of I: First note that $B \subset G$ and $ A \subset G$ so $AB \subset G$

Now i wish to show containment the other way consider $ g\in G $  where g is an arbitrary element of G.

$g =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $ s.t $ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ and $a \neq 0 $

Take $ c \in A $ s.t $c =\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $  take $ d \in B $ s.t $d =\begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $ then $dc  =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

This feels awkward i want to say we have constructed an arbitrary element of G using an element of A and B so $G \subset AB $ thus $G=AB$ by containment both ways.

However it feels oddly not correct and my original assertion of containment of AB in G feels somewhat heavy handed.

Comment: Are $G,A,B$ actually sets?

Comment: No they are all groups

Comment: $A$ with $a=0$ has no inverse.

Comment: Sorry ill edit it a is non zero or its obviously not a group.